# Division of a shape into 4 equal halves by applying 4 colours in sap ui5 gantt chart

Tags: sapui5, gantt-chart

Our new requirement in sap ui5 gantt chart is to divide each shape into 4 halves by applying 4 colours onto it.

Any suggestions/ideas/code sample would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The Gantt Char Elements are SVG Elements, so you should be able to extend `sap.gantt.simple.BaseShape` and implement your own `renderElement` method .

Another way would to draw 4 `sap.gantt.shape.Rectangle` on top of each other and set the `height` & `width` to x/2 and y/2 and adjust their `xBias` & `yBias` to cover 3 quadrants